# Unable to view actual messages in MQExplorer 8

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

First of all, let me admit that I am completely new to MQ, so my question might be trivial.

We are using MQs configured on Websphere and I am trying to use MQExplorer 8 to monitor the same. After connecting using the Queue Managers, I can see the Current Queue Depth, Open Input Count, etc. But I don't get any option to see the actual messages lying in a queue.
I tried googling it, but did not find anything useful.

Here is what I see:
[image]

Can some enlighten me how can I see the actual messages from a queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context menu is your friend.  Right-click on the queue name and select Browse.

[image]

Comment: I don't see these many options in my case. I just see "Compare with..." and "Properties..." options. See the updated image in my original post

Comment: You are looking at Queue Status view. You have right clicked on "WebSphere MQ/<your queue manager>/Queues node in the left pane of MQExplorer. You have to left click on Queues node in the left pane, the right pane will show list of queues. In the right pane right click on queue of your choice and do what @T.Rob has described.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with JMS messages, you can use other tools like [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/?source=directory) to browse and manage the messages in MQ 8 and see the JMS headers etc.